# C++ object in iphone app

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

i'm starting to explore a brand new world for me that is the world of the games.
I've started using the cocos2d framework to get the interface done.
The brain of the game is a c++ class that is called when in the interface happens something.
As this brain should keep track of everything and keep track on what happened in the game, i think that the correct design pattern is the singleton one.
Now my question is :" does anyone have experience in creating singletons in c++ and add those to an iphone app "
Obviously i've googled for a day and read a lot of docs but the informations i've got are not very clear 
Links are welcome! 
thanks

Comment: Does the iPhone even support C++ development? I thought it was exclusively an objective-c device.

Comment: It does, Apple's APIs are in Objective-C, which means one has to use Objective-C++ to really utilize iOS...

Comment: @kevin objective-c is a superset of c++, so basically yes.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the following good enough for your purposes?

```
Singleton& instance()
{
     static Singleton singleton;
     return singleton;
}
```

Comment: Well. i think i have to try it and see , Thanks